# align divs passed the browsers width with a slide in effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I align the following coloured divs next to each other, so that each one is the full width of the browser window (responsive) and only one is display at a time?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpxvjm

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content-area">
  <div class="p1">Page 1</div>
  <div class="p2">Page 2</div>
  <div class="p3">Page 3</div>
</div>

<a class="previous-page" href="#">Previous Page</a>
<a class="next-page"href="#">Next Page</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {background: grey;}

.p1 {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.p2 {
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.p3 {
  background: green;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content-area {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also, when the user selects the previous and next buttons, how can I then push the divs either left or right depending on which anchor link is selected?

Comment: you can try with some jquery slider....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really recommend [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to create the **carousel** effect you are after.

It is super easy to setup, allows for responsive design, is quite compatible with old IE and has features like arrows and dots built in!

---

If you want to *run your own*, i would suggest toggling classes in javascript which leverage css transforms & transitions to ensure maximum performance.

For example,

```
.page{
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px; 
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 transition: .5s;
}
.hide-left{
 transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.hide-right{
 transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

Adding browser specific prefixes where required.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of solution, define parent with (number of pages) x 100% width and each child of page 100% / (number of pages) width :

```js
var currentPage = 0;
$('.previous-page').on('click', function() {
  currentPage--;
  $('.content-area').css('left', (currentPage * -100) + '%');
});
$('.next-page').on('click', function() {
  currentPage++;
  $('.content-area').css('left', (currentPage * -100) + '%');
});
```

```css
body {background: grey;}
.content-area div {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3333%;
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.p1 {
  background: red;
}
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content-area {
  width: 300%;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: left 2s;
  transition: left 2s;
}

.p2 {
  background: blue;
}
.p3 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content-area">
    <div class="p1">Page 1</div>
    <div class="p2">Page 2</div>
    <div class="p3">Page 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="previous-page" href="#">Previous Page</a>
<a class="next-page"href="#">Next Page</a>
```

You can improve the script, i just made it to illustrate the slider.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I've created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/tg9wvzo7/) for what I think it is that you want. I've also created a snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < $(".content-area div").length; i++) {
        $(".content-area div").eq(i).css({
            left: "+=" + parseInt($(".content-area").width() * i, 10)
        });
    }
});

var currentPage = 0; //0th index

$(".previous-page").click(function () {
    changePage(-1);
});
$(".next-page").click(function () {
    changePage(1);
});

function changePage(updown) {
    if ($(".content-area div")[currentPage + updown]) {
        $(".content-area div").animate({
            left: "+=" + parseInt($(".content-area").width() * -updown, 10)
        },1600);
        currentPage += updown;
    }
}
```

```css
body, html {
    background: grey;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.p1 {
    background: red;
}
.p2 {
    background: blue;
}
.p3 {
    background: green;
}
.content-area {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content-area div {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
.next-page, .previous-page {
    z-index:2;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:5px;
}
.next-page {
    right:5px;
}
.previous-page {
    left:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-area">
    <div class="p1">Page 1</div>
    <div class="p2">Page 2</div>
    <div class="p3">Page 3</div>
</div>
<a class="previous-page" href="#">Previous Page</a>

<a class="next-page" href="#">Next Page</a>
```